# Cauchy Sequence Definition and Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

[image]

Both these theorems were discussed in class, I wanted to discuss some doubts regarding theorem 1. Is it possible to say simply from theorem 1 alone that any sequence for which $\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right|\rightarrow 0$ is a cauchy sequence? I can most definitely say $\alpha ^n\rightarrow 0$ as $0<\alpha <1$ so that would seem to imply that if a sequence satisfied the condition $\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right|\rightarrow 0$ it would be cauchy. But at the same time the sequence $\sqrt{n}$ satisfies this condition but is obviously not cauchy as it is not convergent. Could anyone explain what exactly is causing this mismatch and maybe I am assuming more than I was given.

Comment: What is important is $\sum \alpha^{n} <\infty$, not just $\alpha^{n} \to 0$. Note that $\sum (\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n)=\infty$.

Comment: No not enough. You need the successive terms to go to zero sufficiently rapidly in order to ensure Cauchyness. The reason is that Cauchyness, if you look at the definition has the term $|x_n-x_m|$ for sufficiently large $n,m$, and this needs to be made less than a given $\epsilon$. In your hypothesis you only have successive terms. So you need them to decay sufficiently rapidly so that the series converges.

Comment: Another very popular example: $x_n=1+\frac 1  2+\frac 1 3+\cdots+\frac 1 n$.